# Type coercion issue in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, casting

EDIT: This works absolutely fine in Swift 3, which we should all be using by now :)

---

If I have two protocols, `X` and `Y` where `Y` implements `X`, why can't I assign an array of `Y` to a variable with the type `[X]`?

Even more curiously, I can convert it one by one into an array of X, and that compiles fine.

```
protocol X { }

protocol Y: X { }

// Make a test array of Y
extension String: Y { }
let a: [Y] = [ "Hello" ]

// Make it into an array of X - this works absolutely fine
let b: [X] = [ a[0] as X ]

// Why won't this cast work?
let c: [X] = a as [X]
```

I thought that given Y does everything X can do, this assignment should be fine (yea, I lose some type information, but it should at least compile!)

Any ideas?

EDIT: The [current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36578868/13000) points out that it's a dangerous thing to do if you are using mutable arrays - which I didn't get but do now :) However, if my arrays are all immutable why won't Swift let this happen? Even if `c` is a mutable array (i.e. `var c = a as [X]`) why won't Swift copy it, leaving `a` intact?

Comment: Swift generics are invariant. Not sure you can have covariant generics in swift.

Comment: The problem with this code is, that you could add a `Z` to the hierarchy which also derives from X. Now your Array has both `Y` and `Z`, even though `Z` is not a subtype of `Y`.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz: I don't think this is the problem. Infact you can still individually append different types that conform to `Y`. E.g. `struct Z: X {};b.append(Z())`. Now `b` does contain an element of type `String` and an element of type `Z`. And the compiler is fine with that.

Comment: Yup, but appending is different from casting. :) Now you have an `[X]` with a `String` and a `Z`. But if you were to do it as I describe by casting you'd get a `[Y]` with a `String` and a `Z`. Java Arrays are covariant and it lead to exactly these kind of problems.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz: But he does not want to cast `[X]` to `[Y]`. He wants to cast `[Y]` to `[X]`

Comment: I know, but consider this: ` (a as [X]).append(Z())` now you added a Z to an array of Y

Comment: `(a as [X]).append(Z())`

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz: Good point... but it cannot happen for 2 reasons. **1)** `(a as [X])` would create an immutable copy of `a` (so `append` is not available). **2** Even if you use a `var`, the array is copied (since it's a Struct and then a value type). So what you say is not possible and I don't think it's the reason of the error described by the OP. In Java what you say makes sense since Java Arrays are Object but not in Swift.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz: To better explain my last comment look at this example: `var list = [1,2,3]; (list as [Int]).append(4)`. It does not compile because the result of `(list as [Int])` is an immutable value. On the other hand this code does compiler `var list = [1,2,3];var list2 = (list as [Int]);list.append(4)` but since the value list is copied to `list2` the value 4 is added only to `list2`. There is no **interference** between `list` and `list2` so the problem you described cannot happen.

Comment: You're right that in that situation it can't happen. However if you pass it as an inout parameter and then append to it, you'll bump into problems in the same way and swift disallows it.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz: Nope! This code does compile perfectly: `func foo(inout animal:[Animal]) { animal.append(Dog()) }`. Please try it yourself. I appreciate your contribute but please note that providing a wrong answer does not damage only the OP but every future reader of this thread.

Comment: Really? It doesn't compile for me?

Comment: What version of Swift are you running?

Comment: @appzYourLife, yes I had the same, I'm guessing you tried with classes, right? It does not work on protocols, check my edited answer :)

Comment: By the way guys, this works fine in Swift 3

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't work because it could create a few problems. For example:

```
var squares: Array<Square> = Array<Square>()
(squares as [Shape]).append(Circle())
```

Now we have a circle in our Array of Squares. We don't want that, so the compiler doesn't let us. In other languages like Scala you can specify generics to be `covariant`, `contravariant` or `invariant`.

If Swift would let you use **covariant** generics an `Array<Square>` would be a subtype of `Array<Shape>`.

If using **contravariance** an `Array<Square>` would be a supertype(!) of `Array<Shape>`.

But when using **invariant** generics, neither is the subtype of neither.

The easiest way to do it in your case would probably be this:

```
let c = a.map{$0 as X}
```

Now `c` is of type `[X]`.

For more information on type variance and why it can be problematic visit, you can visit [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)).

**EDIT:** After further back and forth, it seems the real problem is, that Protocols allow default implementations and can therefore cause problems. Your code will compile flawlessly when using classes. Here's some code that could potentially lead to problems with protocols:

```
protocol Shape {
    func surfaceArea() -> Double
}

extension Shape {
    func surfaceArea() -> Double {
        return 0.0
    }
}

protocol Circle : Shape {
    func getRadius() -> Double
}

extension Circle {
    func surfaceArea() -> Double {
        return getRadius() * getRadius() * 3.14
    }
}
```

Now, when we upcast between these two protocols, the `surfaceArea()` method returns different values, and Swift doesn't allow it.

Try the same thing with classes, instead of protocols and Swift won't have any problems compiling your current code. This is, to me, kind of a weird decision by the Swift team, but I still think the best way to mitigate is to just use

```
let c = a.map{$0 as X}
```

Comment: Your first block of code does not work for a different reason. The compiler error is `error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type '[Shape]'`. This is **NOT** related to the original question. Would be the same with `var list = [1,2,3];(list as [Int]).append(4)` where we use the exact same type. Please read my comments below the question.

Comment: Nice explanation. In my case I know I'm safe with this cast, but I can see why it's not allowed so hey, I'll just find a different way to do what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: @appzYourLife My question has absolutely nothing to do with mutability and all to do with generics. So what if the code example doesn't compile, _it's the concept that's important_.

Comment: Exactly but the explanation provided here is not the answer to your question. This is not the reason why your last line of code does not compile.

Comment: The compiler throws "Cannot convert value of type '[Y]' to type '[X]' in coercion". That's because `[Y]` is not a subtype of `[X]`. So yes, it is the reason the code doesn't compile :)

Comment: @appzYourLife After sleeping on it, I think I've got your point; if `a` is an immutable array, why can't I make a new array `c` by losing the type information? `a` is untouched, so that's fine and `c` is now an array of `X` so even if that were a mutable array, it doesn't matter because it's a different instance than `a`.

Comment: I also slept on it, and got to the bottom of this. The code DOES work with classes, but not with Protocols, which seems super weird to me.

Comment: @deanWombourne check out my edited answer. However my original point still stands, `[Y]` is not a subtype of `[X]`:)

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz: exactly! *if `a` is an immutable array, why can't I make a new array `c` by losing the type information?*

Comment: I agree , that it should be possible! To make it consistent across classes and protocols.