# Cannot assign protocol array to generic array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift2, generic-constraints

There are some codes below, some gives compile time error some doesn't. Is there a bug or do I miss something about generics here?

**1)** Doesn't work:

```
class DataSource: NSObject {
    var dataObjects: [DataType]

    init<T where T: DataType>(dataObjects: [T]) {
        self.dataObjects = dataObjects //Cannot assign value of type [T] to type [DataType]
    }
}
```

But this works:

```
class DataSource: NSObject {
    var dataObjects: [DataType]

    init<T where T: DataType>(dataObjects: [T]) {
        self.dataObjects = []
        for dataObject in dataObjects {
            self.dataObjects.append(dataObject)
        }
    }

}
```

**2)** Doesn't work:

```
class DataSource: NSObject {
    var dataObjects: [DataType]

    init<T:DataType>(dataObjects: [T]) {
        self.dataObjects = dataObjects //Cannot assign value of type [T] to type [DataType]
    }
}
```

But this works:

```
class DataSource: NSObject {
    var dataObjects: [DataType]

    init<T:DataType>(dataObjects: [T]) {
        self.dataObjects = []
        for dataObject in dataObjects {
            self.dataObjects.append(dataObject)
        }
    }
}
```

**3)**
This also works:

```
class DataSource<T: DataType>: NSObject {
    var dataObjects: [T]

    init(dataObjects: [T]) {
        self.dataObjects = dataObjects
    }
}
```

Also what is the difference between `T where T: DataType` and `T:DataType`

P.S.:DataType is an empty protocol

Comment: What is wrong with `init(dataObjects: [DataType])`? It will still accept an array of anything that conforms to DataType right?

Comment: Sure. But why don't these work, but others do?

Comment: You're right, could be a swift bug

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576596/type-coercion-issue-in-swift/36578868#36578868

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the problem is that your protocol is not inheriting from a reference DataType, while the array expects objects.

For example, `Any` is not always by reference

```
protocol DataType: Any {
}

class DataSource: NSObject {
    var dataObjects: [DataType]

    init<T:DataType>(dataObjects: [T]) {
        self.dataObjects = dataObjects //Cannot assign value of type [T] to type [DataType]
    }
}
```

on the other hand, AnyObject always is:

```
protocol DataType: AnyObject {
}

class DataSource: NSObject {
    var dataObjects: [DataType]

    init<T:DataType>(dataObjects: [T]) {
        self.dataObjects = dataObjects //Works fine
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you declare protocol as class protocol like this: `protocol DataType: class {}`, code will compile.

Comment: @osrl I'm not saying it isn't a swift bug. Arrays should be able to contain `Any` values. But generics are very buggy at the moment, I had a lot of issues with them lately. I am not sure why the 2nd and 3rd work, imho all should work.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused about why `Any` didn't work.